# How does the render function work in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So I know this question has already been asked but I couldn't find what I was looking for. I've been trying to better understand how react works.

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import Button from "@material-ui/core/Button";

function App() {
  return (
    <Button variant="contained" color="primary">
      Hello World
    </Button>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector("#app"));
```

In the example above the render function takes the App component as the first parameter. I think I'm right in saying this is a JSX React element. But how does the render function then call the App function so that is returns its JSX code? And how does it work when its a class component instead of a functional component? I tried looking through React's source code but had trouble finding anything.

Comment: You don't "return JSX code", try reading the docs: https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html

Comment: And see  what `ReactDOM.render` does: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-dom.html#render

Comment: The App function declared does though. It returns a Button component, with a capital B. I am aware JSX is just syntactic sugar for calling React.createElement(), so ultimately its Javascript.

Answer (score 1):

```
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector("#app"));
```

is roughly equal to this

```js
document.querySelector("#app").innerHTML = babel-compiled version of App
```

basically that app component will be handed to babel to be transpiled from jsx to native js, and the it would be put inside that `root`; doesn't matter what kind of thing is that, is it `class`based or`function` based, babel will handle that

Comment: Ok, but at some stage the App function has to be called so that it returns the component. I just don't know where that is done.

Comment: @roberttheboss that happens when you import it from another module and pass to the render; you can log that `<App/>` when you import it, but don't pass it to the `render` and see how it is different

Comment: I'm struggling to understand. Could you link a source that explains this please? Are you saying the App function is being imported somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

If you check the index.html, you will have this:

```
<div id="root"></div>
```

consider this element this as the parent element. this is what render() does behind the scene. first lets choose the parent element.

```
const parentElement=document.getElementById("root")
```

now we need to append some html to it.

```
 const templateElement = document.createElement("template");
```

we create a template element. template element is an actual HTML element that turns some string into some actua html that can be stuck into the DOM. now we jsut created this

```
<template></template>
```

we need to pass some html elements in it. in your eaxample it is `App` component.

```
 templateElement.innerHTML = </App>
```

now we need to append this to the parent element:

```
parentElement.append(templateElement.content);
```

so you can think render function like this.

//instead of Component, you can jsut pass any html code directly. it will eventually be attached to the template element

```
render(Component,parentElement) {
    const templateElement = document.createElement("template");
    templateElement.innerHTML = Component;
    parentElement.append(templateElement.content);
  }
```

in the first line, I create the template element. then I pass a template